# ¿Como hacer que si inicia con la letra A cumplo con los requisitos y si no mostrar que no cumple?

Tags: java, booleano

```
     String frase,palabra;
     Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese una frase que sea de longitud de 5 caracteres: ");
     frase = lector.nextLine();
     
     
     boolean inicioconA = Character.isUpperCase(frase.charAt(0));
     int nameLength = frase.length();
     
     
     if (frase.length() < 5 )
         palabra = "La longitud es: "+nameLength;
     
     else if(frase.startsWith("a")){
            System.out.println("La cadena: "+nameLength+"  empieza con A");
     
     }else{
     palabra = "No comple lo solicitado.";
     
     System.out.println ("La longitud es: "+nameLength);
```

Necesito realizar un programa que solicite al usuario una palabra de 5 caracteres de longitud y que inicie con el carácter (A).
El programa mostrara la longitud de la palabra, la letra con que inicie.
Ademas, mostrara si cumple con lo solicitado o no.

```
Pantalla final.

Ejemplo 1.
Ingrese una palabra de 5 caracteres que inicie con (A): axila
longitud: 5
Primer Carácter: A
La palabra cumple con lo solicitado.

Ejemplo 2.
Ingrese una palabra de 5 caracteres que inicie con (A): excel
longitud: 5
Primer Carácter: e
La palabra no cumple con lo solicitado.

Ejemplo 3.
Ingrese una palabra de 5 caracteres que inicie con (A): Terreno
longitud: 7
Primer Carácter: T
La palabra no cumple con lo solicitado.
```

Comment: Y qué problema tiene tu código actual para cumplir con el enunciado que mencionas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te recomiendo es convertir lo que el usuario ingresa en una variable tipo String, esta la convertirás en un char array, lo que quedara será tomar datos de este array para checar su primer valor así como el tamaño del mismo, ahora solo quedaría utilizar un filtro con un if para comprobar que cumple con lo que se te pide. Esto ya es opcional pero ya que muestras que se meterán varios ejemplos decidí meterlo en un while(true) y aumentar la variable p para que se entienda mejor en qué ejemplo vas.

```
 int j=1
while(true){

System.out.println("Ejemplo "+j);  

Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 

System.out.println("Ingrese una palabra de 5 caracteres que inicie con (A): ");  

String str= sc.nextLine();              
 char[] c = str.toCharArray(); 
System.out.println("Primer Carácter:  "+c[0]);             
System.out.println("Longitud:  "+c.length );
if (c[0] == ‘a’ && c.length == 4){

System.out.println("La palabra cumple con lo solicitado. ");

} else {

System.out.println("La palabra no cumple con lo solicitado. ");

}
j++
  }
```

Comment: Además del código, no estaría de más una explicación de qué es esto y por qué así.

Comment: @SuperG280 Perdón, iba a editar mi comentario hoy en la pc, la respuesta la puse en el móvil y no me dejaba publicarla cuando combinaba texto con código

Comment: Estuve revisando el código, pero me dice que todas las palabras que no cumple con lo solicitado, hasta hice la prueba con axila y tampoco.

Comment: @JimmyRamirez Me parece que puede ser un error que cometí en la equivalencia de c.length, en lugar de 4 pon 5.

Comment: Si lo corregí, pero el error esta con la letra que inicia con la A, tiene que ser diferente a esa letra para que no cumpla con lo solicitado.

Comment: Si esta bien el código, ya vi revise bien, pero la cadena no termina¿como hago para que termine cuando el código esta bien?

Comment: @JimmyRamirez Quita el while(true) o agrega un break cuando se cumple con las características que necesitas

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias por la ayuda.